# Taylor's Theorem Question

Tags: calculus, analysis

Assuming Taylor's Theorem holds:
Given $$F(x)=f(b)-f(x)-\frac{f'(x)}{1!}(b-x)-\cdots-\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)}{(n-1)!}(b-x)^{n-1}$$

Show that:
$$F'(x)=\frac{-f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}(b-x)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$F(x) = f(b) - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j!}f^{(j)}(x) (b-x)^j$$
so, by the formula of the derivative of the product
$$F'(x) = 0 - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{j!} \left[ -f^{(j)}(x)j(b-x)^{j-1} +  f^{(j+1)}(x) (b-x)^j  \right] =$$
$$= \mbox{ everything cancels out } = - \frac{1}{(n-1)!} f^{(n)}(x) (b-x)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Well that was easy enough.. thanks.